# Get rid of Signed Java Applet Security Dialog

Tags: java, applet

this might be a ridiculous question.

I have a signed applet which only read and write on the client's computer file system.

I can purchase a digital certificate from the Well known authority like Verysign or Thawte etc. to sign the applet.

**If i sign applet using above mentioned authority can i get rid of this ambiguous Security verification held by Java Plug-in ?**

> someone says in SO that you can configure policy file and you can get
>   rid of this. may i know how ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the UAC popup on Windows Vista and later? If so, code signing won't get rid of the popup. What it does do, however, is make it so that instead of the yellow dialog stating "Publisher: Unknown", the user will get a blue dialog stating the publisher name you used for signing. It's used to either look more professional, or to reassure the user that the application was written by you and not an imposter. To actually get rid of the popup, the user would need to disable UAC on their computer.

Comment: *"If i sign applet using above mentioned authority can i get rid of this ambiguous Security verification held by Java Plug-in ?"*  What is ambiguous about it?  Signing an applet with a trusted certificate will change the message, but will not remove it.  If it did disappear completely, that would be a security bug.

Comment: @JamesT I think the Java Applet is died because of this ambiguous dialog.

Comment: @JamesT i can run applet from my eclipse ide without signing it and having a full control. i saw one policy file in my project's bin folder, what is that ? in it i an see grant all line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can help you here. I'm not familiar with Java applets or policy files; I commented because it sounded a lot like you were referring to the UAC dialog. However, it looks like your issue is something I haven't dealt with before. If I knew how to help, I would. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get rid of the dialog is to import the certificate into the JRE trusted certificate store. Another solution is to modify the Java policy file.
Just have a look into Oracle's documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html#gcexdl