# How to avoid java Security Information popup?

Tags: java, security, keytool, client-certificates, truststore

Problem - Java security information popup appears when applet based application loads in the browser.

[image]

When I check *"Always trust content from the publisher"* and click run, the application runs and certificate is added to java user trusted certificates list.

[image]

When I run the application the next time, the Security Information popup does not appear.

My questions are -

***How can I avoid the security information popup for other users logging into the same computer?***

It is a shared desktop used by multiple users and every time a new user logs in and uses the applet based application, the security information popup appears.

***How can the certificate be added to a centralized location (perhaps system trustsore?) and not to user profiles so that whenever a new user logs into the computer and uses the application, the security warning does not appear?***

What I've tried until now:

- Added the client certificate to java keystore on the computer. After
  this I logged into the application again, the popup still appeared.
- Added client certificate to jre\lib\security\cacerts - it didn't help either.

Comment: Refer to this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387387/get-rid-of-signed-java-applet-security-dialog

Comment: This is a system administration question, not a programming question.  If in a AD/domain set up, check serverfault, otherwise superuser

Comment: In general, keep in mind that the Applet technology is outdated. Current browsers stopped to support Java Applets (
https://www.theverge.com/2016/1/28/10858250/oracle-java-plugin-deprecation-jdk-9), and even Oracle decided to remove Applet support from newer Java versions.

With new Java licensing policy for Java 8 (valid since 1st January 2019), you should consider that security updates for Oracle Java 8 now are available only for customers with commercial support contract.

Comment: Seriously, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176390/set-jre-to-use-windows-trust-store-specifically-the-users-trust-store